# I can't set background image on Gnome Terminal 3.14

Tags: gnome-terminal

how I can change the background image in Gnome-Terminal 3.14.2? I was using one before updating to the latest version, but it was replaced by default background colors.

Comment: As far as I know, it was removed as part of a massive code cleanup which in turn allowed more easily fixing bugs and improving the code. Probably it was too complex and buggy code for too little benefits. The reasoning from the main developer was something along the lines that no other type of application allows you to set a custom background, why should the terminal be any different then. (I'm not arguing or trying to protect anyone's opinion, just sharing my vague knowledge.)

Answer (score 5):

Gnome-terminal's background feature has been removed since 3.8.1. Though I couldn't find this in the official release notes, but this is all known by now and they don't want that feature be back. This is one of the discussion assuring https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=161798

Note: This is community Wiki and if anyone finds the reference of this feature removal, add it to the answer by editing this.