# How to set a image as background of the gnome terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

How can I set my terminal background to what @RaduRădeanu has? See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use any image as your terminal background:

1. Select your image of choice. I will use this:

[image]

2. Go to the terminal menu: `Edit`->`Profile Preferences`. The preferences window open up. Go to the 'Background' tab as shown below:

[image]

3. In the background image, select your image and set your opacity level. There you go:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because I'm on 16.04, but this doesn't work in the `gnome-terminal` on my system - the background tab isn't there.

Comment: Background image support was indeed removed from `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: @egmont that's a bummer. Any clear reasons for that?

Comment: Discussion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/615155/i-cant-set-background-image-on-gnome-terminal-3-14

Comment: No longer works

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a picture to your terminal background (and I believe that this is the case, although I didn't find this flower picture) you need to open your terminal's Profile Preferences `(Edit > Profile Preferences)` and select `Background option`.

Now you can see several background options for the Terminal. By default, `Solid Color` option is selected for the Terminal background and beneath it you can see `Background Image` option. Select `Background Image` option, browse and select the image file to be used as the background.

Once you have selected the image file, you can see the changes in real-time – your Terminal screen shall have a new background image instead of the old age solid colour.

Comment: in the past I have seen this background image option ... however its not there on 16.04