# Is there a terminal that allows setting of a background image

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome-terminal

Based on the answer to [I can't set background image on Gnome Terminal 3.14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615155/i-cant-set-background-image-on-gnome-terminal-3-14) I have given up trying to set a background on gnome terminal.  In the link (or maybe in a link from that link) it is mentioned that xfce-terminal will allow a background image.  However the only package I can find in the Ubuntu 16.04 repos is xfce4-terminal which doesn't seem to allow it either.

Is there a terminal out there that will let me easily set a background image that runs in Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04 or do I need to switch Desktop Environments completely?

Answer (score 2):

You can *always* run any of the terminal emulators in any of the desktop environments, there's no need to switch desktop just for that. E.g. you can run `konsole` (KDE's terminal emultor) under the GNOME desktop, or `gnome-terminal` under KDE, etc.

Newer `gnome-terminal` version have indeed removed the support for background image. Notable terminal emulators that use the same terminal emulation widget as `gnome-terminal` (namely `vte`, preferably the GTK+-3 based version rather than the old unmaintained and quite buggy GTK+-2 based one) and do support background image are `Terminix` as well as `xfce4-terminal` version 0.8, both are easy to compile and install on Xenial.

There are plenty of other terminal emulators (not based on `vte`) out there, I'm sorry but I cannot tell which ones support background image (if any) of out the box on Xenial.

Comment: Terminator too.

Comment: @muru Terminator version 0.9x which use the GTK+-2 based VTE does support background image. The bzr branch using GTK+-3 (no tarball release yet) does not. I do not recommend using VTE's GTK+-2 version. It's heavily buggy, misses lots of cool new features that went into the GTK+-3 based one, and is no longer maintained.

Comment: All true, perhaps, but that doesn't change that a) Terminator as currently available on any Ubuntu release uses the old VTE, and b) will continue to use that old VTE on all of those releases, and c) *is* reasonably usable despite all that (I have encountered exactly 1 bug in nearly four years of usage).

Comment: Fair enough, I've stated my recommendation, and everyone's free to use whatever they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Qterminal and it has a setting in the preferences, I use Lubuntu with LXQT and it's extremely [customizable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129526/is-customizable-a-valid-english-word) with the help of various other programs.

```
sudo apt install qterminal
```

Comment: Thankyou. I used to use xfce4-terminal and was very happy with it until I got a 4k monitor and turned on font scaling (HiDPI). I found that with a background picture enabled, the terminal font loses it's crispness (antialiasing?) with font scaling enabled. Qterminal doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Xfce4 terminal *does* allow setting background. I don't know how you tried to set a background. Here is the procedure.

1. Open the terminal after installing it.
2. From **Menu** -> **Edit** -> **Preferences**, Go to **Appearance** Tab.
3. Now under **Background** section, select **Background Image**. This will enable two more fields. One is for selecting the background image file and another is for setting the scaling option of the image. Browse to the file to set an image.

   Here is an image of the preference dialog

   [image: preference window]

   And here is an image of xfce4 terminal with background

   [image: xfce4 terminal with background]

Comment: Be aware that xfce4-terminal as shipped in 16.10 (and older) uses Gtk+ version 2, and in turn a more than 5 year old, unmaintained, quite buggy version of vte (the widget doing the actual terminal emulation) whereas gnome-terminal uses a pretty new one. By switching from gnome-terminal to xfce4-terminal one does get background image support, but reverts back to a much worse actual terminal emulation.

Comment: Not a problem at all practically.

Comment: For the record: `vte` since the gtk2 days received fixes for segfaults, temporary display corruptions, permanent corruption of scrollback data, got a 10x speed boost, no longer stores the scrollback plaintext on the disk, can rewrap the contents on resize, supports true colors and italic text, emits newer escape sequences for keys with modifiers, supports mouse clicks beyond column 223, and a whole lot more. These were just the few probably most important ones that suddenly occurred to me. It's up to you (or anyone reading this) to decide if background image outweighs all of these combined.

Comment: So after a massive upgrade xfce4-terminal does seem to do background images.  However as pointed out it uses libvte which in current versions has eliminated background images.  Therefore, the days of it doing background images is numbered.  In daily use there are no bugs from the old vte stuff, so I'm using it but I would like a terminal that plans on keeping background images. Also it doesn't seem to be able to keep multiple profiles.  So xfce4-terminal is only a temporary solution.